# Python to parse web page for 'title'

Tags: python, regex, parsing, module

I'd like to be able to parse a web page and return any  element that has a title containing exactly 4 letters.

For example:

```
<li><a href="test.com/dogs" title="dogs"></a></li>
<li><a href="test.com/cat" title="cat"></a></li>
<li><a href="test.com/horse" title="horse"></a></li>
<li><a href="test.com/eels" title="eels"></a></li>
```

In this example, I'd like to return an array containing 'dogs' and 'eels' since the title contains exactly 4 characters. How can I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: XML parsers exist. Since you're asking about Python, do a Google search for "beautifulsoup".

Comment: How often must be explain per day that markup should be parsed with HTML or XML parsers and not with anything else? A trillion times? -1 from me

Comment: @user1833746 In the OP's defense, he did ask 'how can I go about doing this', an answer to which would be something like Jack Maney suggested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903868/python-url-extract-from-html/13903924#13903924

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regular expressions reliably.  http://htmlparsing.com/python.html has examples of how to use a parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Using that, you can do something like this:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = # put url here
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
text = page.read()
page.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

L = []
for x in soup.findAll('li'):
    link = x.a
    if link.has_key('title'):
        if len(link['title']) == 4:
            L.append(link['title'])
print L
```

Comment: Dude.. This will work fine. `Beautifulsoup` is just a `.py` file you can import like this: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: For some reason it's not coming back with anything. I've tried doing the 'soup.findAll' on 'li' and 'a', neither will return anything even when I try to print x in the for loop

Comment: Still no luck :/ Comes back with []

Comment: Are you sure? i tested it by pasting your html code directly into the `soup` string and the output was: `[u'dogs', u'eels']`

Comment: What's the url that you're using?

Comment: It's a private link. I think I'm running into login issues due to running it locally. I agree that putting it into the string seems to work. Thanks for your help..I should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that parse html  with re considered bad virtue, but i do like staright forward approach.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import re
 res_array = []
 for line in open('inputdata','r'):
     res = re.findall('title=\"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\"',line)
     if res :
         res_array.append(res[0].split('"')[1]) 
 print res_array
```